# Update value from a form after click on object C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this piece of code, where it runs a function (MouseTracker) after clicking on a label
this MouseTracker, should capture a mouse position x and y after pressing the OK in dialog result.

```
namespace AdvancedStashHelper
{
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
        public int xTemp;
        public int yTemp;

        public Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MouseTracker()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show("Move your cursor to position and press ENTER");

                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    xTemp = MousePosition.X;
                    yTemp = MousePosition.Y;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        private void orbTransLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new(MouseTracker);
            thread.Start();

            orbTransXPos.Text = xTemp.ToString();
        }

        private void orbAltLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new(MouseTracker);
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here it's, first time when you click on the label, nothing happens, but after you click the second time, the value is updated with previous mouse position.

This should function like this:

1. click on label
2. run the dialog that says to press enter to capture mouse position
3. update the values on form after pressing ok
4. do this for all labels with different mouse position values

Comment: Why do you find it surprising? `orbTransXPos.Text = xTemp.ToString();` runs immediately after you start the thread, since that's the point of a thread.

Comment: There's no need for a thread here. Winforms has built-in events for tracking mouse events over form controls.

Comment: Why is there a thread at all? You want to read xTemp in the main thread AFTER the other thread has shown the MessageBox. A clear order of things to happen. But threads run in parallel. So you already build Racing conditions into your code through using threads but you don't do anything you need a thread for.

Comment: to be honest, I'm a beginner, still learning, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your info the code was simply as it is

```
namespace AdvancedStashHelper
{
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
        public int xTemp;
        public int yTemp;

        public Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MouseTracker()
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Move your cursor to position and press ENTER");

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                xTemp = MousePosition.X;
                yTemp = MousePosition.Y;
            }
        }

        private void orbTransLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MouseTracker();

            orbTransXPos.Text = xTemp.ToString();
            orbTransYPos.Text = yTemp.ToString();
        }

        private void orbAltLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MouseTracker();

            orbAltXPos.Text = xTemp.ToString();
            orbAltYPos.Text = yTemp.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```